# What is the source code of Paged List?

Tags: c#

When i send the (pageNumber,PageSize) to the PagedList function
I don't understand what does it work

```
ToPagedList(pagenumber, pagesize);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a project site: https://github.com/troygoode/PagedList

```
collection.ToPagedList(pagenumber, pagesize)
```

> Creates a subset of this collection of objects that can be individually accessed by index and containing metadata about the collection of objects the subset was created from.
>
> **pageNumber**: The one-based index of the subset of objects to be
>   contained by this instance.
>
> **pageSize**: The maximum size of any individual subset.

This extension method is defined in `PagedListExtensions.cs`: https://github.com/troygoode/PagedList/blob/master/src/PagedList/PagedListExtensions.cs